# System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException when converting from System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord to XML

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-winevent

I'm encountering the same issue as mentioned at
https://serverfault.com/questions/743515/my-event-log-has-corrupted-dacl-write-attributes-in-4656-file-audit-events/852636#852636 where there are some invalid characters in the event logs and therefore using .ToXML() fails with the exception:

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException Cannot convert value
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>

irrelevant data omitted

```
<Data Name='AccessReason'>%%1538:   %%1804
    %%1541: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4416: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4417: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4418: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4419: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4420: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4423: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-1513010315-1120)
    %%4424: %%1801  D:(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-4261485934-2742084322-151301031亖퍲翾</Data>
```

> to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character. Line 19, position 117."

How could I strip the invalid characters out? I'm thinking the following might be the process:

1. converting to string (ToString() doesn't seem to work, when outputting via Write-Host it simply outputs the name of the object type)
2. removing the invalid XML characters using .replace and regex
3. convert back/serialize to System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
   object (somehow?)
4. convert to XML (with .ToXML())

How would I achieve steps 1 and 3 of this process?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I'm not sure how to do that with PowerShell. System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord is not a type that I can create and I can't really provide a security log file with this issue in. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord(v=vs.110).aspx shows that there is no constructor for the data type so I can't create this using a string. I can't even show converting a string as System.String does not contain a method named 'ToXml' in PowerShell. Can you suggest how I could do what you want without providing the event log?